# How can I fix the undefined operator in the last expression: trial = trial / numtrials * 4?

Tags: java, undefined, operator-keyword

```
    // write static methods here
    public static double [] calcDarts(double [] trial, int numtrials)throws IOException
    {
        double x;
        double y;

        for(int n = 0; n < numtrials; n++)
        {
            x = Math.random();
            y = Math.random();

            double radius = (Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y,2));

            if(radius <= 1)
                trial = trial / numtrials * 4;                                  

        }
    }
```

The error says the last line of code: `trial = trial / numtrials * 4;` `"The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) double[], int."` How can I have it produce a double value for the variable trial?

Comment: You can't divide an array in Java. We don't know what you are trying to do so we can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: My guess is that you want to change it to `trial[n] = trial[n]/numtrials*4`, but that's just speculation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a double array to calculate with an integer. Do it like this: You have to use the double values in the array:

```java
        for(int n = 0; n < numtrials; n++)
        {
            x = Math.random();
            y = Math.random();

            double radius = (Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y,2));

            if(radius <= 1)
                trial[n] = trial[n] / numtrials * 4;                                  

        }
```

But I think it is not good to calculate directly with the parameter. Create inside a Array to put the result and return it or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Yes, that was exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

`trial` is an array of doubles, the operators `/` and `*`are obviously not defined for the use with an array. What you problably want to do is multiplying a *single* number form the array like this:

```
 trial[n] = trial[n] / numtrials * 4;
```